# How to display JSON data in jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, java, json, ajax, spring

I have an ajax call that sends data to a controller. The controller returns a JSON object containing a user object. In my success function I want to open a dialog and display the user's information in the dialog.

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "get",
  url: $(".user-details-link").attr("href"),
  dataType: "json",
  cache: true,
  error: function(jqXHr,textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Error opening dialog:\n" + errorThrown);
  },
  success: function(data){           
   $("#view-user").removeClass("hidden");
   $("#view-user").dialog(dialogOpts);
   $("#view-user").dialog("open");
     
  }
     
});//end ajax
```

This is the code that returns the json object

```
@RequestMapping(value="/admin/user/detail", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody void userDetail(HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam("id") int id)
                throws IOException, JSONException, ServletException{
    MMUser user = iUserService.getUser(id);
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

    jsonObject.put("user", user);

    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.getWriter().println(jsonObject);
    }
```

I am fairly new to spring so please bear with me. 
The code is working fine. I am successfully returning a json object back to JavaScript. I'm struggling with this part; I want to display the user's details in the #view-user div. #view-user div is displayed inside a dialog. The dialog is also working but it's empty because i don't know how to display the information inside it. Is there a way to use the json object from the server to display my data like this in the dialog?

```html
<div id="view-user">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        ${user.getEmail()}
      </td>
      <td>
        ${user.getFirstName()}
      </td>
      <td>
        ${user.getLastName()}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: which template you are using for view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/admin/user/detail", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody MMUser userDetail(HttpServletRequest request, 
    HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam("id") int id)
            throws IOException, JSONException, ServletException{
   MMUser user = iUserService.getUser(id);
   return user;
}
```

JS

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: $(".user-details-link").attr("href"),
    dataType: "json",
    cache: true,
    error: function(jqXHr,textStatus, errorThrown) {
             alert("Error opening dialog:\n" + errorThrown);
    },
    success: function(data){                    
        $("#email").val(data.email);
        $("#firstName").val(data.firstName);
        $("#lastName").val(data.lastName);
        $("#view-user").removeClass("hidden");
        $("#view-user").dialog(dialogOpts);
        $("#view-user").dialog("open");

    }

});//end ajax
```

HTML

```
<div id="view-user">
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>
     <span id="email"></span>
   </td>
   <td>
    <span id="firstName" ></span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <span id="lastName"></span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! However i used $("#email").text(data.email)  instead.                  
 $("#email").val(data.email) didn't work

Answer (score 1):

In spring instead of sending back a json object, yuo should be doing:

```
MMUser user = iUserService.getUser(id);
return user;
```

Spring will convert the object into json. Having said that in your ajax, the response will be your json object.

```
 success: function(data){                   
                console.log(data.email);

    }
```

Have a look at this example [enter link description here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/)